# Why won't Web Apps install after I click intall in Firefox?

Tags: webapps

I am trying to install a couple web apps (gmail, facebook). I get the prompt in Firefox to install them. I click install and nothing happens. Am I forgetting to do something?

Comment: I think this is about a Unity feature that doesn't apply to modern versions of Ubuntu running GNOME Shell. It could also be about installable web apps, which [Firefox no longer supports](https://support.mozilla.org/gl/questions/1415477).

Answer (score 2):

They won't give you a message like "The app has been successfully installed" or anything like that. But you can see these apps in the `top panel`, under the `envelope` button. Please check whether its there, if not, then they have not been installed. This is how my apps look after I have installed them:
[image: My apps]